# How to connect the signal and slot in multi-thread program?

Tags: multithreading, qt

The mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QtCore>

/* ****** Thread part ****** */
myThread::myThread(QObject *parent)
    : QThread(parent)
{
}

void myThread::run()
{
    while(1){
        qDebug("thread one----------");
        emit threadSignal1();
        usleep(100000);
    }
    exec();
}

myThread2::myThread2(QObject *parent)
    : QThread(parent)
{
}

void myThread2::run()
{
    while(1){
        qDebug("thread two");
        emit threadSignal2();
        usleep(100000);
    }
    exec();
}
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    onethread = new myThread(this);
    onethread->start(QThread::NormalPriority);

    twothread = new myThread2(this);
    twothread->start(QThread::NormalPriority);

    connect(onethread, SIGNAL(onethread->threadSignal1()),
            this, SLOT(mySlot1()));
    connect(twothread, SIGNAL(threadSignal2()),
            this, SLOT(mySlot2()),Qt::QueuedConnection);
}

void MainWindow::mySlot1()
{
    ui->textEdit1->append("This is thread1");
}

void MainWindow::mySlot2()
{
    ui->textEdit1->append("This is thread2");
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    ui->textEdit1->append("textEdit1");
    ui->textEdit2->append("textEdit2");
}
```

The mainwindow.h:

```
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QThread>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class myThread : public QThread
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
    myThread(QObject *parent = 0);
    void run();

signals:
    void threadSignal1();
};

class myThread2 : public QThread
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
    myThread2(QObject *parent = 0);
    void run();

signals:
    void threadSignal2();
};

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
    void mySlot1();
    void mySlot2();

private slots:
    void on_pushButton_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    myThread *onethread;
    myThread2 *twothread;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Please check the above code. It can give the `qDebug` output normally while the textEdit1/2 have no any output. And it seems to be a multi-thread signal/slot connect issue. Who can help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define the slots as slots:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

public slots:
    void mySlot1();
    void mySlot2();
...
```

Also a few other things. You don't need the `exec()` call in each of the threads. They are going into an endless loop anyways and would never reach that statement. And, the purpose of `exec()` is to start an event loop in the thread so that it can **receive** and process events, like having its own slots. You are just emitting.

Are you sure this connection works?

```
connect(onethread, SIGNAL(onethread->threadSignal1()),
        this, SLOT(mySlot1()));
```

It should probably be:

```
connect(onethread, SIGNAL(threadSignal1()),
        this, SLOT(mySlot1()));
```

I believe `QueuedConnection` will be implied for the connections because they are targeting a slot on an owner in a different thread than the emitter.

Comment: You are completely right. And all bugs were pointed out! Really thanks!